# asp.net core ServerGarbageCollection not working visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

Asp.net core 1.1.2

windows server 2016

visual studio 2017

after migrating my project from vs 2015 to 2017 i made a release and published my website but now memory usage constantly grows in production server

At vs 2015 i had this in my project.json :

```
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },
```

but after migrating to vs 2017 csproj is like this

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>xxxxx</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>xxxxx</PackageId>
    <UserSecretsId>xxxxxxx</UserSecretsId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.1.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;dnxcore50;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
    <ServerGarbageCollection>true</ServerGarbageCollection>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

but garbage collection is not working. any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Does the generated runtimeconfig.json contain `"System.GC.Server": true`? if so, i suspect the error is more related to your application than the build tooling.

Comment: yes "System.GC.Server" is set to true. the same app was working without high memory usage before migration